# I want to recover reverted changes from GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-pages, github-for-windows

I have committed my changes on Git

Then Reverted changes from Git so changes also gone from local

I need to recover specific file changes.

**After my revert some other changes also pushed but changes not exist in my files**

Answer (score 0):

You can still go back to the commit where you made the changes. You can create a branch out of that commit.
`git branch new-branch-name <commit-id>`

Also, you can check out one particular file from that particular commit.
`git checkout <commit-id> <path-to-file>`